# How can I stop a specific Doubleclick ad from ever being served to me again?

Tags: browser, advertisements

I support internet ads but would like to block only certain adverts.

<sub>My personal experience with "tailored ads" is actually a very disappointing one. Despite not caring much about blocking tracking information (with one notable exception), you visit one product page on Amazon one day and for 24 hours since that all the "personalized" ads I get are about Amazon and that specific product. Sometimes that happens when I visit specific websites too, like a rather well known Dutch pizza franchising's. That's just sad.</sub>

I know how to block all adverts, but that is not what I want to do. Is it possible to prevent certain adverts? I'm perfectly okay if blocking those ads means being served other ads in their place.

Comment: I understand why block all exists, it's easier. What you're after would be impossible IMO as it would have to know what the AD is. EG, it would look at the Advert Name - what happens if the Advert Name changes, or another advert comes in with a new Name although the same advert.

Comment: @DaveRook eh, I thought it'd justify why I'm _not_ looking forward to "JUST INSTALL ADBLOCK LULZ" as an answer.

Comment: Retargeting is becoming enormously popular, it's not just doubleclick that will be re-advertising to you. To block all retargeting ads would be a huge undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, I know... but it keeps turning up in the search results, and the answers are incorrect. You CAN turn off the "doubleclick ad" redirects, by changing a few settings in your Google Account settings and installing an extension to your browser.

1. Go to [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/) in Google
2. Under "Personal Info" change everything to the most limited access ("rather not say", allow "only those I interact with" to view, etc.)
3. Under "Data and Privacy" restrict access for all options here as well.
4. (b) MOST IMPORTANT: Under "Data and Privacy" scroll down a little to "MY AD CENTER", click on this, then on the upper right side of the banner, turn "Personalized Ads" OFF. This will effectively kill ad.doubleclick.net.
5. Install the [DoubleClick Opt Out extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iba-opt-out-by-google/gbiekjoijknlhijdjbaadobpkdhmoebb?hl=en). This is basically an add-on for Chrome (it's also available for IE and Firefox) that permanently opts you out of the DoubleClick cookie that Google uses for ads. Basically, this ensures you still retain the "opt-out" status in the future even after clearing your history and cookies

That should do it.

After performing these steps, Google will no longer search your machine for personalized information to redirect you to ads, it will simply show generic ads when it shows ads now, avoiding the dreaded "Can't Access Site" error caused by ads.doubleclick.net.

I can now go to all the sites that previously brought up the ad.doubleclick.net redirect with no problem at all. It has effectively turned it completely off, and has made browsing and accessing these sites much easier.

Enjoy...! ;-)